# Green screen photo merging

Tags: java, android

I have 2 photo's, the first one is a background, the second one is a photo of someone with a greenscreen.
I'd like to merge the 2 of them using a android app.
So I'll end up with a image of someone with the background i chose.

Is this even possible with the android sdk? and if so could you explain to me how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, if someone writes the software to do it. There is no built-in functionality in the Android SDK to do this.

Comment: I think that's kind of a dead end for me. Would PHP be able to do it? If so I suppose I could upload the images and have PHP generate the new image.